# Convert String to Double and then back to String

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, currency

The problem is my API response returns **orders[indexPath.row].price** as a String. The string is actually a double value like 3.55973455234. I need to convert this value to something like 3.56 and display in UI label. I have been pulling my hair since morning to achieve this. Why is Swift so horrible at conversions?

```
        cell.lblPayValue.text = orders[indexPath.row].price
```

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41558832/335858), it may have a good explanation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use **NumberFormatter** but you would need to convert it back to a NSNumber...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

if let number = formatter.number(from: orders[indexPath.row].price) {
    cell.lblPayValue.text = formatter.string(from: number)
}
```

But please don't create N NumberFormatter. Create one and store it somewhere.

Comment: Hey It doesn't seem to be hitting the if statement can we do something so that it always goes within the if block?

Comment: Could be a problem with the decimal separator. When parsing, locale should be always set correctly.

Comment: Maybe your number is formatted in a different manner than the locale suppose (because NumberFormatter is locale specific). Try with the updated code. Anyway, try to not use this solution because you'll create *maybe* unnecessary ressources. But NumberFormatter still offers some advantages.

Comment: No problem. But as I said, I hope you don't create a NumberFormatter inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because it would create a formatter for each cell. Try to create one somewhere (`viewDidLoad` if you want), store it as a property and access it everywhere.

Comment: @Ackman don't use decimal. It is a currency. You should display it accordingly to the user Locale. To convert from string to double just use the Double initializer

Comment: Noted. Thanks a ton :) I see we do not need the formatter instance being created every time.

Comment: @Ackman Oh yeah. If you want fancy formatting (currencies) try to change the `numberStyle` to something else. But don't forget that it is locale specific.

Comment: Hey what do I do if I want a "$" sign in front of the text amount on label?

Comment: no worries got it did : cell.lblPayValue.text = "$" + cell.lblPayValue.text! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

if let price = Double(orders[indexPath.row].price), let formattedPrice = formatter.string(for: price) {
    cell.lblPayValue.text = formattedPrice
}
```

1. So you get the double value first with the if-let
2. Then you use it to set your `cell.lblPayValue.text`
3. You use the formatter to get a currency format on your `Double`

Comment: Nope. Does not set any value.

Comment: Are you sure that `orders[indexPath.row].price` has a valid double? Check the updated answer btw with `NumberFormatter

Comment: No need to cast to `NSNumber` any more. The OP has stated that `price` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Conversions are pretty straightforward IMHO. You can create a new Double by using the initialiser with a string. Then you have an optional Double. This can then be converted to a formatted String. So...

```
    let price: String = "3.55973455234" // your price
    let text = String(format: "%.2f", Double(price)!)
    print(text) // prints 3.56
```