# Formatting a negative Double into currency in Swift

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I want to format a Double value such as `-24.5` into a currency formatted string like `-$24.50`. How would I do that in Swift?

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558832/how-to-format-a-double-into-currency-swift-3), but it ends up formatting as `$-24.50` (negative sign after the $), which is not what I want.

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve this, besides something like this?

```
if value < 0 {
    return String(format: "-$%.02f", -value)
} else {
    return String(format: "$%.02f", value)
}
```

Comment: NumberFormatter. I really strongly advise against using `String(format:)` in Swift in general, let alone for currency formatting. For one, there are currencies that don't use `$`, and there are locals which don't use a `.` as the decimal separator (e.g. `$1,234,567.89` might be `€1.234.567,89` in Europe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter):

```
import Foundation

extension Double {
    var formattedAsLocalCurrency: String {
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        return currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self))!
    }
}

print(0.01.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $0.01
print(0.12.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $0.12
print(1.23.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $1.23
print(12.34.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $12.34
print(123.45.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $123.45
print(1234.56.formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => $1,234.56
print((-1234.56).formattedAsLocalCurrency) // => -$1,234.56
```

Comment: Question for the masses: Why does [`NumberFormatter.string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1418046-string) return an optional? When can it fail?

Comment: It is strange since `localizedString` does not return an optional.

Comment: Not sure, what happens when you pass an `NSNumber(bool: true)`? But he inconsistency with `localizedString` is weird.

Comment: @HAS It's actually `NSNumber(value:)`, even for `Bool`, and it just gets treated as 1.0

Comment: Sorry, wasn’t in front of a computer, thanks for checking!

Comment: Creating `NumberFormatter` instances are expensive like date formatters, etc. Better to cache the formatter into a private static variable.

Comment: @TruMan1 Yeah, you're right. Though I'm not sure if there's a one-size-fits-all suggestion I could make for where to store the cached instance