# Convert a double value to pt-BR real - Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Double, and i need show in label numbers in currency format, pt-BR format.

```
private var myValue: Double = 0.0
myLabel.text = "\(self.myValue)"
```

**
i need convert this Double to pt-BR real
**

i try this:

```
   let convert = self.myValue as NSNumber
    
   myLabel.text = "\(convert)"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a Double into Currency - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558832/how-to-format-a-double-into-currency-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use NumberFormatter for this task.
Here is an example:

Playground view:

[image]

```
let currency = 10.50

let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let result = NumberFormatter()
    result.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt-BR")
    result.numberStyle = .currency
    
    return result
}()

let label = UILabel()
label.text = formatter.string(for: currency)
```